# Rails, JSON Object, jQuery, Auto-Complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm using this jquery autocomplete plug-in with rails: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

I can't figure out how to format my results, both in my Rails controller and in my javascript file.

I have something like this in my controller...

```
@query = params[:q].downcase
@json = User.all(:login => /^#{@query}/)
respond_to do |format|
  format.js  { render :json => @json.to_json(:only => "login"), :layout => false }  
end
```

And then this in my script.js file...

```
    $("#form").autocomplete('/url', {
    width: 320,
    dataType: 'json',
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300
    })
```

But I can't figure out how to parse the data, so my autocomplete just gets a raw array of all my results at once.

How do I process the JSON in the script.js file and/or in my controller for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually discovered a JSON example in the Demo. It looks like this:

```
    function format(user) {
        return user.login + " (" + user.name + ")";
    }
    $("#login").autocomplete('/url', {
        multiple: false,
        delay: 100,
        dataType: "json",
        parse: function(data) {
            return $.map(data, function(row) {
                return {
                    data: row,
                    value: row.login,
                    result: row.login
                }
            });
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return format(item);
        }
    }).result(function(e, item) {
        $("#content").append("<p>selected " + format(item) + "</p>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#toptions) for that plugin, there is no `dataType` option. You might also be mixing config options from one fork of the plugin with source from another fork.

Have you tried the default (pipe-delimited, if my memory serves me correctly) format for the suggestion data fetched from the server?

BTW, I did find this fork [here](http://blog.echolibre.com/2009/06/jquery-json-autocomplete/) which adds JSON support to the autocomplete plugin.